# C# : How can I do an other request in my socket after the close of it?

Tags: c#, sockets, console-application, communication

I create a console application in c# in order to communicate between a server and a client with socket.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    LoopConnect();
    SendLoop();    
}

private static void SendLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a request: ");
        string req = Console.ReadLine();

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
        _clientSocket.Send(buffer,0,buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None);
        _clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

        if (req != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                var receivedBuffer = new byte[2048];
                int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer, SocketFlags.None);

                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
                string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Received : " + result);
                _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _clientSocket.Close();


            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT");
                    _clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    _clientSocket.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void LoopConnect()
{
    int attempts = 0;
    while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            attempts++;
            _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
        }
        catch (SocketException) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection attenpts: "+ attempts.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.Clear();
}
```

I do a first request and i get my response but when I do an other request I have this error :

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.'

Can I modify my code to do a request after the close of my socket ?

Comment: you do `_clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);` after first string was sent. But when are you initializing `_clientSocket` with new socket for the second ittem to be sent?

Comment: @oleksa I remove something in my code I had `LoopConnect` after my `_clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);` but it still doesn't work

Comment: I do not know how your code looks like now. Please update source code in the question. PS there is answer already and it looks to be correct

Answer (score 1):

Move `LoopConnect();` into the `while` loop to get

```
...
Console.WriteLine("Enter a request: ");
string req = Console.ReadLine();

LoopConnect();

byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
_clientSocket.Send(buffer,0,buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None);
_clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;
...
```

This should ensure you open up a socket whenever you want to send a request.

In addition you might want to move the shutdown and close operations for the socket to a `finally` block at the end of the try catch being left with

```cs
try
{
    var receivedBuffer = new byte[2048];
    int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer, SocketFlags.None);

    byte[] data = new byte[rec];
    Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
    string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    Console.WriteLine("Received : " + result);
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    if (se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT");
    }
}
finally
{
    _clientSocket.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Since the `finally` no longer uses `Shutdown` and `Close` make sure to free the resources at the end of the program with

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    LoopConnect();
    SendLoop();   

    _clientSocket.Shutdown(S);
    _clientSocket.Close(SocketShutdown.Both); 
}
```

Comment: I have updated the finally block. You can reuse the socket if you use `Disconnect(true)` instead of `Shutdown` and `Close`. See docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Disconnect_System_Boolean_

Comment: After the receive of my response I can't write in the console